# Dynamically selecting objects in node.js to remove if/else if

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring

I'm working in node.js and trying to eliminate an if/else if by changing a segment of code based on one variable. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this more dynamically. I have two sections of code that are identical except one calls http and one https, depending on how a URL begins:

```
const { http, https } = require('follow-redirects');
if ((thisURL.split(":")[0] == "http")){
  const request = http.request(requestOptions, response => { 
    alist.href = response.responseUrl;
    resolve(response.responseUrl);
  });
  request.end();
}
else if ((thisURL.split(":")[0] == "https")){
 const request = https.request(requestOptions, response => { 
    alist.href = response.responseUrl;
    resolve(response.responseUrl);
  })
  request.end();
}
```

It feels like there should be a way to call the http or https directly based on the split of the string instead of need the `if/else if`, but is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using if/else, you can get the `protocol` and use `array#includes` to check for the protocol. You can create `follow-redirects` based on a protocolLookup.

```
const { http, https } = require('follow-redirects');
const [protocol] = thisURL.split(':');
const potocolLookup = {"https": https, "http": http};

if (["https", "http"].includes(protocol)) {
 const request = potocolLookup(protocol).request(requestOptions, response => { 
    alist.href = response.responseUrl;
    resolve(response.responseUrl);
  })
  request.end();
}
```